# Cannot link portaudio library as a static library

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, portaudio

I need to link a library (portaudio) as a static library. When I do the following

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static -L/media/Data/lib/.libs -lportaudio prova.cpp
```

linking fails telling me

```
/tmp/ccuoQi1J.o: In function `main':
prova.cpp:(.text+0x190): undefined reference to `Pa_Initialize'
prova.cpp:(.text+0x1bc): undefined reference to `Pa_GetDeviceCount'
prova.cpp:(.text+0x1d8): undefined reference to `Pa_GetDeviceInfo'
prova.cpp:(.text+0x248): undefined reference to `Pa_OpenDefaultStream'
prova.cpp:(.text+0x27c): undefined reference to `Pa_CloseStream'
prova.cpp:(.text+0x280): undefined reference to `Pa_Terminate'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

while, without -static option, linking gives no errors

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -L/media/Data/lib/.libs -lportaudio prova.cpp
```

I need to link statically all libs, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

From [gcc linking options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options),

> **-static**
>
> On systems that support dynamic linking, this prevents linking with
>   the shared libraries. On other systems, this option has no effect.

Here, all your undefined symbols are in `libportaudio` library which is a shared library and you are preventing linking to it by specifying `-static` and hence the error. gcc is unable to find a static version of `libportaudio` in the specified library path ( `/media/Data/lib/.libs`)

Why do you want to statically link that shared lib? Any specific reason?

You may want to read this to understand more about how gcc treats [shared and static libraries.](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_25.html)

Comment: I want to link statically that shared lib because I don't want to install it in target system; this because filesystem is not persistent and I'll have to install library at every boot. I don't know if it can be done, maybe I have to build library to a static version.

Comment: I've tried the following with no results:
`arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wall -static -I../portaudio/include ../portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a prova.cpp`
 and 
`arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wall -static -I../portaudio/include -L../portaudio/lib/.libs -lportaudio prova.cpp`
 .
Library with .a extensions is in the directory "../portaudio/lib/.libs"

Comment: now I'm linking in this way: `/home/francesco/Dropbox/poli/bi/not/ip/cross/arm-2007q3/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wall -static -I/home/francesco/Dropbox/poli/bi/not/ip/portaudio/include -L/home/francesco/Dropbox/poli/bi/not/ip/portaudio/lib/.libs prova.cpp` . Content of portaudio/lib/.libs is `file ../portaudio/lib/.libs/*
../portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a:   current ar archive
../portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.la:  symbolic link to '../libportaudio.la'
../portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.lai: libtool library file
` . By the way I get the same result :|

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded the newest source for PA from http://www.portaudio.com/download.html and are trying to statically link the library to one of their test programs on OSX, try out the following make command (cd to the root of your downloaded portaudio folder first):

```
gcc -Iinclude examples/paex_sine.c lib/.libs/libportaudio.a -framework CoreAudio -framework AudioToolbox -framework AudioUnit -framework CoreServices
```

This will produce a program "a.out" that will generate a sine wave for a couple of seconds. At least this is what happened when I tested it out on Yosemite.